# What kinds of Mounts can a Paladin get besides Warhorse?

Tags: paladin, adnd-2e, adnd-1e, mount

I distinctly recall AD&D paladins being able to have mounts like griffons, dragons, and planar variants, but I cannot locate these rules. I'm aware Cavalier Paladins had some of these, though I'm not sure how that interfaced with their Holy Mount rules if at all. It seems we ran a Planescape campaign and someone had an elemental variant, following some "your mount is the equivalent of the nearest" or whatever. Perhaps exotic mounts were a dragon magazine or Skills & Powers/Player’s Option addition?

In sum: looking for the list of non-warhorse mounts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*The Complete Paladin's Handbook* by Rick Swan provides the information you seek. Some example exotic mounts are: unicorns, pegasi, griffons, giant eagles, elephants, lions, tigers, dire wolves, hippocampi, dolphins. There are also others; and DM's choice is also left out as an open-ended option. The book also recommends establishing rules for such exotic mounts. An example rule is to restrict the mount's hit dice to be below half the paladin's level.

Comment: Ah, that's an extensive list, thank you. I found dragon mounts as an option for 10 character points in Dragon Magazine #257. As to establishing guiding rules, the cavalier scale of pegasus/7th, hippogriff/9th, griffon/11th is nice. It also gave racial specialist female elves unicorns 4th level, but 6th level might be a good between. Such a table can then be a hit die/power reference for other mounts/level. :)

Answer (score 1):

*Unearthed Arcana* (UA) 1e page 15 shows Cavaliers can handle and ride other mounts. And the Paladin gains the Cavalier abilities.

> "4th level a female elven cavalier (and only a female elf) can ride a unicorn as a steed.
>   At 7th level the cavalier can handle and ride a pegasus as a steed.
>   At 9th level, the cavalier can handle and rige a hippogriff as a
>   steed.
>   At 11th level, the cavalier can handle and ride a griffon or
>   a similar creature (DM's judgement) as a steed."